# Trying to get fish to face direction it's moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So far I'm making an app, and the early stages of it will just be a fish swimming around a small box. I made code that alters the fishes direction randomly and if it reaches certain x or y values to keep it within visibility of the camera. Unfortunately my C# knowledge is limited and I can't figure out how to make it turn the direction it is , this is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FishBehavior : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 2f;
    float moveSpeed = 0f;
    private Rigidbody2D rigid;
    public float rotateSpeed = 2f;
    public bool isPredator = false;

    void Start () {
        rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
        InvokeRepeating("FishMovement", 3f, Random.Range(2f,6f));

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        int num = Random.Range(1, 10);
        if (transform.position.x >= 11.5)
        {
            speed = -2;
            rigid.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
        }
        if (transform.position.x <= -11.5)
        {
            speed = 2;
            rigid.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
        }
        if (transform.position.y >= 5.07)
        {
            rigid.velocity = new Vector2(Random.Range(-2, 2), -2);

        }
        if (transform.position.y <= -4.65)
        {
            rigid.velocity = new Vector2(Random.Range(-2, 2), 2);
        }
    }
    void FishMovement()
    {
        int fishSpeed = Random.Range(-3, 3);
        if (fishSpeed != 0)
        {
            moveSpeed = Random.Range(-2, 2);
            rigid.velocity = new Vector2(fishSpeed, moveSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

Anything helps thanks

Comment: `Unfortunately my C# knowledge is limited ` is this related to c# knowledge  or math/algorithm?

Comment: @Eser in my opinion, it would be more math/algortihm related, but since this is for unity it actually is neither since theres a neat "out of the box" function for that. OP would just need to decouple the rigidbody controlling the movement and orient the gfx child object looking along the velocity vector. ofc this is only one option (another would be to have the rigidbody rotate randomly before moving). https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html

Comment: @yes How about posting an answer?

Comment: @Eser yeah i probably should, but i dont want :S Also, thinking about it, the rotation could just be set by `Rigidbody.rotation` aswell.

Comment: @yes I looked at the first link but am confused on what the target would be considering moves randomly, and how would I optimize the second one for a 2D game?

Comment: its current position plus the velocity. but yeah, i guess just randomly rotate the rigidbody with either https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-rotation.html or https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MoveRotation.html instead of changing the velocity (you could still scale it if you want different speeds)

Comment: @yes I've implemented what you sent me but it just seems to spin constantly regardless of direction rather than rotate according the the direction it's moving in, I tried putting it in the method where the random direction change occurred but nothing happened, I would assume because the change is minimal every time it's called.